# iPhone is broken, how can I still access my contacts?

Tags: backup, contacts, screen

I broke my iPhone last weekend and the screen remains blank/black even if I connect it to a computer running iTunes. Is there a way I can still access my contacts?

Comment: Did you use iCloud syncing for your contacts?

Comment: How did you break your phone? Can you give some more details?

Answer (score 5):

If you synced them through iCloud, then the easiest way is to go to  [iCloud](http://icloud.com). From there you can go to Contacts, select them all using the gear menu on the bottom left and export the vCards. You also can open iTunes and see if it has already been set to sync contacts to an app on the computer or if iTunes has a backup that you could restore onto any iPod, iPhone or iPad to access them / cloud sync them.

Otherwise if you were backing up the device on your computer you can recover the data with [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com).

Or, if the phone still boots up (e.g. you just broke the screen or something like that), you can also try using some utilities like [PhoneView](https://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) (I'm pretty sure there are others, but I've used only PhoneView so I don't know if/how they works).

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to accessing your contacts, but if this works you have you iPhone and contacts back.

I had a similar problem last week. After a night my iPhone was turned off. The battery was not empty.

Press and keep the power and home button for about 10 seconds. If it's the same problem, the iPhone should boot up.